# SSR or TRIAC for 8kW three-phase kiln

Tags: three-phase, solid-state-relay, pid-controller, triac

I have a PID-controller that uses VAC as the control signal. The kiln will be heated and cooled in stages with specific speed (t oC per hour), mainly for ceramics with crystal glazes.

Manufacturer says the controller is capable of controlling both SSR (AC-controlled) and TRIACs directly, but insists that TRIACs are "better".

What are the benefits (if any) of making my own TRIAC stack besides cost?

Comment: As far as I understand, an AC-controlled SSR *is* a triac + optical isolation ?

Comment: Please list the alternatives so that a benefit analysis can be made. Why would you use a triac stack rather than just one triac? Please link the data sheet for the controller and state which page has the manufacturer's recommendations mentioned in your question.

Comment: yeah, that's why I'm asking here... I don't think there is a point in basically making my own SSR, but my knowledge is lacking :D

Comment: @Andyaka I'm sorry, there isn't one. It was stated in the personal email-conversation. The data sheet provides basic schematics on connecting both AC and DC controlled SSR, as well as TRIAC's

Comment: Please describe your system better. Temperature control of an AC line device can be done 3 ways: 1) Simple on/off with hysteresis, 2) Conduction angle control, 3) Zero-crossing bursts. If you have a PID, then you don't want #1. For a system with a large thermal mass, #3 is often preferred because it produces less electrical noise. Which options does your controller support?

Comment: @Mattman944 Here's an excerpt from the regulator manual(google translated to english). "The main controller outputs provide non-contact switching of AC circuits with voltage up to 400 V at current up to 0.3 A or control of thyristors (triacs) with a trigger current up to 1 A. Switching is carried out in zero supply voltage"

Comment: @JohnI Not reading the original language you have, *"Switching is carried out in zero supply voltage"* suggests to me what in English is called *zero-crossing*. Which given this is a kiln makes the most sense to me, also. Not having much information, it may be that they prefer triacs as they already perform zero-crossing and can drive the triacs using their own well-tested zero-cross method. If using SSRs then the SSRs may be zero-cross or random and here they may really just prefer direct TRIAC control rather than indirect. Perhaps you can write and ask them.